# Executing dbcc in PHP+sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sqlsrv

I have a script in PHP with sqlsrv, which connects to a SQL Server 2016 database, and executes SQL queries and retrieves results. Up to here, no problem.
But if I try to execute a DBCC CHECKIDENT ($Table, RESEED, $NextIdentity) or a BACKUP DATABASE, as soon as the command "prints" something, the function sqlsrv_query returns, and returns FALSE.
Example:

```
sqlsrv_query( "BACKUP DATABASE MYDB TO DISK = 'C:\\Backup\\MYDB.bak'" );
```

The sqlsrv_query returns FALSE, and sqlsrv_errors contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01000
            [SQLSTATE] => 01000
            [1] => 3211
            [code] => 3211
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]10 percent processed.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]10 percent processed.
        )

)
```

For some DBCC commands, it is possible to use them specifying "WITH TABLERESULTS", which would solve the problem, but the specific DBCC that I need does not support that.

Ideally I would like a solution that is synchronous (for instance, waits the end of the backup before returning) and that allows me to check if the DBCC or BACKUP operation was successful.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `WarningsReturnAsErrors` value to `0`? It's default value is `1`.

Comment: Yes, nothing changed